# installing libxml in ruby 1.8.7 on linux mint

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linux-mint, libxml-ruby

this is the result when trying to install ->  extconf failure: need libm

```
virtualrails@jay ~ $ sudo gem install libxml-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname() in -lnsl... no
checking for atan() in -lm... no
checking for atan() in -lm... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/bin/ruby
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
 extconf failure: need libm


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-2.6.0/ext/libxml/gem_make.out
```

And this is the output of mkmf.log:

---

```
have_library: checking for atan() in -lm... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I. -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/include  -g -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/lib   -fno-builtin conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -Wl,-R/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -Wl,-R/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -L. -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/lib -ltcmalloc_minimal -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-static -lm  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:3: error: ‘atan’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:3: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
conftest.c:3: error: for each function it appears in.)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))atan; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I. -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DAI_ADDRCONFIG=0 -I/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/include  -g -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/lib   -fno-builtin conftest.c  -L. -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -Wl,-R/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -Wl,-R/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/ruby/lib -L. -L/opt/rubystack-2.0-0/common/lib -ltcmalloc_minimal -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-static -lm  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lruby-static
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { atan(); return 0; }
/* end */
```

---

i am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualrails/ in virtualbox 4.2.8

using gem 1.3.5

its contains two errors:

- conftest.c:3: error: ‘atan’ undeclared (first use in this function)
- /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lruby-static

the first error 'atan' is easy to solve but the second one not really sure if one library is missing or if the is a bigger problem beging all this

Comment: I suggest you to try to upgrade to `1.9.2` by `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1`

Comment: forget to mention that i also have rails installed, that wont mess with my project already running on ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/xml4r/libxml-ruby#requirements:

> libxml-ruby requires Ruby 1.8.4 or higher. It is dependent on the
>   following libraries to function properly:
>    - libm (math routines: very standard)
>    - libz (zlib)
>    - libiconv
>    - libxml2
>   If you are running Linux or Unix you’ll need a C compiler so the extension can be compiled when it is installed.

make sure you have all of these before building gem

Comment: i been trying to install the libm for the pass 5 hours, still no luck

Comment: @Santiago Morel Berni, `libm` is supposed to be installed already, you may look for `libm` file in `/usr/lib/` folder. Make sure libxml2 is intalled

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev

sudo gem install libxml-ruby
```

Comment: What is this? Can you explain how this answers the question?